# To get \n instead of n in echo -e command in shell script

Tags: shell, command, echo

I am trying to get the output for the echo -e command as shown below

Command used:

```
echo -e "cd \${2}\nfilesModifiedBetweenDates=\$(find . -type f -exec ls -l --time-style=full-iso {} \; | awk '{print \$6,\$NF}' | awk '{gsub(/-/,\"\",\$1);print}' | awk '\$1>= '$fromDate' && \$1<= '$toDate' {print \$2}' | tr \""\n"\" \""\;"\")\nIFS="\;" read -ra fileModifiedArray <<< "\$filesModifiedBetweenDates"\nfor fileModified in \${fileModifiedArray[@]}\ndo\n egrep -w "\$1" "\$fileModified" \ndone"
```

cd ${2}

**Expected output:**

```
cd ${2}

filesModifiedBetweenDates=$(find . -type f -exec ls -l --time-style=full-iso {} \; | awk '{print $6,$NF}' | awk '{gsub(/-/,"",$1);print}' | awk '$1>= '20140806' && $1<= '20140915' {print $2}' | tr "\n" ";")

IFS=; read -ra fileModifiedArray <<< $filesModifiedBetweenDates

for fileModified in ${fileModifiedArray[@]}

do

egrep -w $1 $fileModified 

done
```

Original Ouput:

```
cd ${2}

filesModifiedBetweenDates=$(find . -type f -exec ls -l --time-style=full-iso {} \; | awk '{print $6,$NF}' | awk '{gsub(/-/,"",$1);print}' | awk '$1>= '20140806' && $1<= '20140915' {print $2}' | tr "n" ";")

IFS=; read -ra fileModifiedArray <<< $filesModifiedBetweenDates

for fileModified in ${fileModifiedArray[@]}

do

 egrep -w $1 $fileModified 

done
```

How can i handle "\" in this ?

Answer (score 1):

For long blocks of text, it's much simpler to use a quoted here document than trying to embedded a multi-line string into a single argument to `echo` or `printf`.

```
cat <<"EOF"
cd ${2}

filesModifiedBetweenDates=$(find . -type f -exec ls -l --time-style=full-iso {} \; | awk '{print $6,$NF}' | awk '{gsub(/-/,"",$1);print}' | awk '$1>= '20140806' && $1<= '20140915' {print $2}' | tr "\n" ";")

IFS=; read -ra fileModifiedArray <<< $filesModifiedBetweenDates

for fileModified in ${fileModifiedArray[@]}

do

egrep -w $1 $fileModified 

done
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `printf` to have a better control:

```
$ printf "tr %s %s\n" '"\n"' '";"'
tr "\n" ";"
```

As you see, we indicate the parameters within double quotes: `printf "text %s %s"` and then we define what content should be stored in this parameters.

In case you really have to use `echo`, then escape the `\`:

```
$ echo -e 'tr "\\n" ";"'
tr "\n" ";"
```

Interesting read: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/40596)

Comment: cant we handle this in echo -e since i need to implement this with some script and i stuck at this point

Comment: can you please suggest me the solution

Comment: As per what you show in your answer (move it to the question, please), you have a broader problem. Please indicate the whole scope of it, because apparently you are using a lot of pipes and awks and many things... and we could try to find an easier solution.

Comment: I just updated in the question please suggest me now

Comment: @user3679139 Please try to make a bigger effort to describe your problem. What do you do with `filesModifiedBetweenDates`, etc? As it is not clear, you'd better indicate the full problem you are facing with some sample input and desired output.

Comment: I just updated my overall question please can you suggest me the expected output to it

Comment: @user3679139 I am not going to answer anything else until you put some effort on describing your problem. I solved your original issue. Maybe you could try to answer a new question instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i just solved it by your explanation to my initial problem i just splitted my echo -e to get my desired onput thank you fedorqui for your help

Comment: @user3679139 you are welcome. You can give a read to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center. It is a good overview that will for sure help you in the future. Also, remember you can accept an answer once your problem is done.

Comment: There's no real need to use `%s` here; `printf 'tr "\\n" ";"\n'`. The main reason `printf` is superior to `echo -e` is that it is portable, not that it can simply the handling of escaped characters.